# Redirect to url from load balancer without CORS error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I was wondering if any of you know how to achieve that a GCP load balancer redirect to an url with "CORS enabled". What do I mean by that?, well I have the following scenario:

- One load balancer that has to redirect to other load balancers depending on the path of the URL (**LB A**)
- "Simple" load balancer that has many backends attached (**LB B**, **LB C**, etc)

So my flow is as follow:

- **LB A** (/pathB) -- redirect -> **LB B**
- **LB A** (/pathC) -- redirect -> **LB C**

This works as expected if requested by   a `simple HTTP Request` (like cURL or Postman) but fails if its requested on a website. Why?, because the preflight `OPTIONS` request is redirected and that brings a CORS error `Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request`, and even if the `OPTIONS` request is skipped, a simple `GET` request will also have a `redirected` response without the CORS headers (which will fail).

Is this possible?, if so how can I achieve it?, I tried to add a cors policy on **LB A** but a LB can't have a `routeAction` with a `urlRedirect`.

Practically I just want to inject the CORS headers on the 301 Response to avoid the error.

Comment: When you mention that you already add the cors policy LB A, would that be the routing rules under load balancer then "advance host and path rules" Then when you click the "Code Guidance" then search for add Cors Policy it will give you a sample yaml guide?

Comment: Yes! @YvanG. The code sample use a `routeAction` which is not combinable with `urlRedirect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time searching for a solution I finally got to a "working" conclusion.

If you want that a google's load balancer inject some headers (specially cors headers) on a request thats redirected to another domain, then **you are out of luck** (also mentioned [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Redirect-to-url-from-load-balancer-without-CORS-error/m-p/509243#M2156)). Even with the new LB version it seems that is not possible (at the moment, am sure this feature will release in some time). Maybe there is a way of doing it, but neither the docs nor the api seems to tell you how.

Then you just "can't" do this?. Well, no, the `classic` load balancer has something call an `Internet NEG` which is like having "external backends" you can point to, so I just create various NEGs to meet my needs and attach them in the LB as backends. So I accomplish my example as follow:

- If **LB B** has the domain *lb-b.com* and **LB C** has *lb-c.com*

  - Create 2 Global NEGs (Internet NEGs) with the `full domain name` as *lb-b.com* and *lb-c.com* respectibly
- Then create 2 backend services on **LB A** with each one associated with each NEG.
- Finally select `Advanced host and path rule` and create one `Path rule` for each LB, for example for **LB B**:

  - Create a path rule of `/pathB/*`
  - Select the option `Route traffic to a single backend`
  - Use path prefix as `/` (if you want to "remove" the `pathB` prefix on the forward)
  - Select the backend service you previously create corresponding to *lb-b.com*

Comment: I see, I was actually confused about the statement on “flow is as follows” my initial thought is that the LB A will redirect to LB B and LB C. Upon seeing the posted answer it was the domain from LB B and LB C that was needed to redirect.

Is it ok  if I request if we can edit the question to this format below:

LB A (/pathB) – redirect –> lb-b.com

LB A (pathC) – redirect → lb-c.com

Is it ok also if I can post an answer regarding the cors error that you are having I believe there is other work around for that error message under coding level.

Comment: No, indeed the redirect is made from LB A to LB B (and LB C accordingly) based on the incomming path, In short my need is to have a reverse proxy in my LB A to proxy the request to others LBs based on the path. First I was trying to do it with urlRedirect, then I switch to NEGs because the limitations urlRedirect has

Comment: I understand, I believe there are different approaches for such scenarios which I hope I can also post it as answer to help other users to see what other workaround that we can use.

Comment: Yes!, this kind of problems have very little docs or resources :/. On my answer I put a link to a GCP Community Question I created with some other ways to handle this, hope it helps others. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing this information with documentation and guidance as a workaround for handling and enabling CORS.

Another thing that I can think of for this scenario is by using cloud function for redirects and CORS headers. You can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#cors) as a guidance for this scenario. Let me also share another [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors#functions_http_cors-csharp) where you can see different code sample.

To use a reverse proxy in front of the load balancer that can handle the CORS header and the redirecting request we can use Apache or Nginx. For this scenario we can follow this [link](https://geekflare.com/enable-cors-apache-nginx/) as a guidance.